# Removing element of a list from another list - ValueError : list.remove(x): x not in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please clearify this concept.

I'm trying to remove the element of one list from another list but getting this error **list.remove(x): x not in list**

here is an example of simplicity that im trying to do. although im using a list of strings.[Click here to see Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD98s.png)

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
list2 = [1,2,3,6,8]
list1.remove(i for i in list2)
```

Comment: The dupe target tells you how to do it, but here's why this doesn't work: `list.remove` expects a single element, not an iterable. The element it's been given here, is the generator (expression), which does not exist in the `list1`.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).